# Linux script issue

Tags: sql, linux, bash

I am trying to run below script on a server, but I am getting line 15: ERROR:: command not found. Here is the script. EOF`statement is the 15th line

```
#!/bin/bash


/opt/oracle/products/dbclient/sqlplus -S -L username/us3r_mdpI14@servicename <<EOF
set feedback off trimspool on
spool /home/cznygf/scripts/home/mdpi/catchallreport/proc/catchall.txt
select ORDER_NUM, MODEL_YEAR, PORT, MDPI_PURCHASE_ID, TO_CHAR(RESERVED_DATE ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MM') RESERVED_DATE,
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MM') SYSTEM_DATE,
trunc(24 * (SYSDATE - RESERVED_DATE)) DIFF_HOURS
from INVENTORY_NEW
where PURCHASED  is null
and trunc(24 * (SYSDATE - RESERVED_DATE)) > 1;
spool off;
EXIT
EOF
```

line 15: ERROR:: command not found

Comment: You are apparently missing `sqlplus` on the server.

Comment: ... or at least in your `$PATH`.

Comment: First, confirm that sqlplus is installed on your server. Then, make sure that it is in the PATH of the user executing the script.

Answer (score 2):

First. Make sure you have `sqlplus` installed on the server. You'll never get this to run without that.

Second. Check what executable `sqlplus` calls by running `which sqlplus`. It's possible that the executable is in a location that is not in the `$PATH`.
Replace `sqlplus` with the full output of `which sqlplus` in your script.

If you are sure `sqlplus` is installed and `which sqlplus` doesn't return anything useful, you may just have to search for the file. I have no clue where it might be, but the sqlplus docs and the `find` command might help.